# Save ARKit screenshot in AR Resource Group

Tags: swift, arkit

I am trying to save an UIImage into AR Resource Group at runtime in order to detect it back after. You can read this group using referenceImagesInGroupNamed:bundle: but there is not indications on how to write it.

I am trying the following :

```
//step 1: list all reference images
print("BEFORE = ", ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) ?? "None")

//step 2: take snapshot
let snapshot = self.viewController?.sceneView.snapshot()
//optional crops and image processing here

//step 3: add shapshot to bundle
let referenceImage = ARReferenceImage(snapshot.cgImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, physicalWidth: someComputedPhysicalWidth)
// ??

//step 4: list all reference images and ensure new one is added
print("AFTER = ", ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) ?? "None")

//step 5: relaunch session if intempted to redirect it now
sceneView.session.pause()
configuration.detectionImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil)!
sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

Will what is stored in the group be saved after I close the app ? Can I delete something in it ? If write access is impossible I guess I can save the created referenceImage parameters somewhere and rebuild referenceImage when needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot amend the contents of the default folder at runtime, although you can create images on the fly and access them later.

To create images dynamically you can use the following methods:

[image]

In order to maintain concurrency e.g. accessing any saved `snapShots` you will need to save them to the device, and then access them later.

Here is a basic implementation in which you can take a snapshot of your `ARSCNView` and them load them on the fly.

The issue here (which you will need to fix) is determining the `physicalSize` of the `ARReferenceImages` which need to be provided in metres:

```
extension ViewController{

    //------------------------------------------------
    //MARK: Get CIImageProperyOrientation From UIImage
    //------------------------------------------------


    /// Converts A UIImageOrientation To A CGImagePropertyOrientation
    ///
    /// - Parameter orientation: UIImageOrientation
    /// - Returns: CGImagePropertyOrientation
    func cgImagePropertyOrientation(_ orientation: UIImageOrientation) -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        switch orientation {
        case .up:
            return .up
        case .upMirrored:
            return .upMirrored
        case .down:
            return .down
        case .downMirrored:
            return .downMirrored
        case .leftMirrored:
            return .leftMirrored
        case .right:
            return .right
        case .rightMirrored:
            return .rightMirrored
        case .left:
            return .left
        }
    }

    //---------------------
    //MARK: File Management
    //---------------------

    /// Returns The Documents Directory
    ///
    /// - Returns: URL
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {

        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory

    }

}

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
        guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        //2. Get The Targets Name
        let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!

        //3. Get The Targets Width & Height
        let width = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
        let height = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

        //4. Log The Reference Images Information
        print("""
            Image Name = \(name)
            Image Width = \(width)
            Image Height = \(height)
            """)

        //5. Create A Plane Geometry To Cover The ARImageAnchor
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
        planeNode.opacity = 0.25
        planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

        //6. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

        //7. The Node Is Centered In The Anchor (0,0,0)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //8. Create AN SCNBox
        let boxNode = SCNNode()
        let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

        //9. Create A Different Colour For Each Face
        let faceColours = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.cyan, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.gray]
        var faceMaterials = [SCNMaterial]()

        //10. Apply It To Each Face
        for face in 0 ..< 5{
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = faceColours[face]
            faceMaterials.append(material)
        }
        boxGeometry.materials = faceMaterials
        boxNode.geometry = boxGeometry

        //11. Set The Boxes Position To Be Placed On The Plane (node.x + box.height)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0 , 0.05, 0)

        //12. Add The Box To The Node
        node.addChildNode(boxNode)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //1. Create A Reference To Our ARSCNView In Our Storyboard Which Displays The Camera Feed
    @IBOutlet weak var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!

    //2. Create Our ARWorld Tracking Configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    //3. Create Our Session
    let augmentedRealitySession = ARSession()

    //4. Create An Array To Store Our Reference Images
    var customReferenceImages = [ARReferenceImage]()

    //5. Create An Identifier So We Can Create A Unique Name For Each Image
    var identifier = 0

    //--------------------
    //MARK: View LifeCycle
    //--------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        setupARSession()

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    //--------------------------------
    //MARK: Creation Of Dynamic Images
    //--------------------------------

    /// Saves The Snapshot Of An ARSCNView
    @IBAction func saveScreenShot(){

        //1. Create A Snapshot Of The ARView
        let screenShot = self.augmentedRealityView.snapshot()

        //2. Convert It To A PNG
        guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot) else { return }

        //3. Store The File In The Documents Directory
        let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("custom\(identifier).png")

        //4. Write It To The Documents Directory & Increase The Identifier
        do {
           try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
           identifier += 1
        } catch  {
            print("Error Saving File")
        }

        //5. Load The Custom Images
        loadCustomImages()
    }


    /// Loads Any Custom Images From The Documents Directory & Appends Them To A Custom [ARReferenceImage]
    func loadCustomImages(){

        //1. Get Reference To The NSFileManager
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        //2. Get The URL Of The Documents Directory
        let documentsDirectory = getDocumentsDirectory()

        do {

            //a. Get All Files In The Documents Directory
            let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

            //b. Loop Through Them And If The Path Contains Our Custom Prefix Then Convert To CGImage & Then ARReference Image
            for file in fileURLs{

                if file.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("custom"){

                    if let arImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: file.path), let arCGImage = arImage.cgImage{

                        /* Here You Will Need To Work Out The Pysical Widht Of The Image In Metres */

                        let widthInCM: CGFloat = CGFloat(arCGImage.width) / CGFloat(47)
                        let widthInMetres: CGFloat = widthInCM * 0.01

                        let arReferenceImage = ARReferenceImage(arCGImage,
                                                                orientation: cgImagePropertyOrientation(arImage.imageOrientation),
                                                                physicalWidth: widthInMetres)

                        arReferenceImage.name = file.lastPathComponent

                        customReferenceImages.append(arReferenceImage)
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch {

            print("Error Listing Files \(documentsDirectory.path): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


        //3. Set Our ARSession Configuration Detection Images
        configuration.detectionImages = Set(customReferenceImages)
        augmentedRealitySession.run(configuration, options:  [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors ])


    }

    //---------------
    //MARK: ARSession
    //---------------

    /// Sets Up The ARSession
    func setupARSession(){

        //1. Set The AR Session
        augmentedRealityView.session = augmentedRealitySession

        //2. Conifgure The Type Of Plane Detection
        configuration.planeDetection = []

        //3. If In Debug Mode Show Statistics
        #if DEBUG
        augmentedRealityView.showsStatistics = true
        #endif

        //4. Run The Session
        augmentedRealitySession.run(configuration, options:  [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        augmentedRealityView.delegate = self

    }

}
```

This example works fine from a practical perspective and as a quick mock-up , although as I noted you will need to look at how to correctly ascertain the size of the dynamically created Reference Images etc:

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks ! That's fine, also came to the conclusion that I could not write anything in AR Resource Group. Have to find a smart way to evaluate the physical size with some hit testing until some depth maps are provided.